# Read JAVA serialized object from database into PL/SQL object

Tags: java, oracle, serialization, plsql, deserialization

Is there any way to read a java serialized object from an oracle database into a pl/sql object type? Meaning:

I have in Java an object of type Person which I serialized it and saved it as a BLOB in my Oracle database.

I want in Pl/SQL to define type Person like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person AS OBJECT
```

with the same attributes and methods as in java and then read my Java serialized object from the database Into my PL/SQL Person Object.

Java: Person java_person -------> serialization ------> write it to the database
PL/SQL: plsql_person Person -----> read from the database the java_person into plsql_person

Comment: Do you not have a `Person` class that you can use to know the attributes of the serialised object which you can use to create the type?

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question. I want to read from the database my java object and save it into a plsql object of type person.

Comment: How can you deserialise the object if you don't know what attributes it has? Conversely, if you know what attributes it has then why do you need to dynamically declare the object type?

Comment: You don't undestand the question. I know how to define my type Person with the same attributes and methods as my Class Person in Java. I already did that. What I want is to read from the database the java object into my pl sql object.

Comment: "I want in Pl/SQL to define type Person like `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person AS OBJECT` with the same attributes and methods as in java" ... so you already have this? Why did you say you want it then?

Comment: My bad. What I''m actually interested IS what follows after that.

Comment: Please provide the Java `Person` class (and, if you have it, what you used to load the serialised data) and the DML for the `CREATE TYPE Person` statement. Do you want this in Java outside the database or do you want it internal to the database (tricky but you can use `CREATE JAVA SOURCE` or the `loadjava` utility to embed java into the database)?